# Prueba F con muchas variables en R

Tags: r, algoritmos, ciencia-de-datos

tengo un modelo de regresión logístico (logit) el cual tiene en total 40 variables. Quisiera hacer una prueba F para todas las combinaciones posibles
por ejemplo: 
que con ayuda de un paquete en R pueda hacer la prueba F para un modelo cualquiera, por ejemplo de 4 variables.
x1, x2
x1, x3
x1, x4
x2, x3
x2, x4
x1,x2,x3
x1,x2,x4
x2,x3,x4
Espero hacerme entender. 
Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Cómo sería una prueba F? ¿Podrías plantear un tu pregunta un ejemplo en código R? Con esto sería más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Agrega por favor lo que has intentado o investigado, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Va una respuesta basada en [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300595/automatically-create-formulas-for-all-possible-linear-models) solución. Lo que hace es generar todas las posibles combinaciones no repetidas de términos en la fórmula y ponerlas en la una lista. Luego con `lapply()` generar una lista de modelos con esas fórmulas. Estrictamente extrae el estadístico $z$ para cada término en cada modelo.

Al no tener datos tuyos para el ejemplo uso los datos `mtcars`, pero la lógica debería ser la misma.

```
data(mtcars)

columnas <- names(mtcars)[-9] #La 9 es am que será la dependiente

n <- length(columnas)

indices <- unlist(lapply(1:n, function(i) 
  combn(1:n, i, simplify = FALSE)), recursive = F)

formulas <- sapply(indices, function(i)
  paste("am~",paste(columnas[i],collapse="+")))


lapply(formulas, function(f) {
  modelo <- summary(glm(f, family = "binomial", data = mtcars))
  modelo$coefficients[ , 3]}
  )
```

Mencionas que estás trabajando con 40 variables independientes. En ese caso el número de combinaciones va a ser considerable y no creo que sea manejable en una computadora normal (quizás en un servidor con muchísima RAM se pueda). Ocurre a que medida que agregamos variables la complejidad del problema aumenta exponencialmente.

> En mi computadora con 8 Gb de RAM no logré siquiera generar las fórmulas para un ejemplo con 40 variables.

No sé cuál es el problema de fondo que estás tratando de resolver, aunque intuyo que buscas hacer selección de predictores/variables/features o como prefieras llamarlas. Si es el caso te sugiero explorar algún método específico para el problema, como los modelos lasso o Fordward Stepwise Selection (puedes buscar en este mismo sitio, hay preguntas sobre el tema). El lasso tiene mucha ventajas en este caso, además de ser muy eficiente en términos computacionales tiene muy buenos criterios para selección de predictores y además hace penalización de coeficientes. Tiene variantes para modelado predictivo e inferencia.